# How to right align for the first component

Tags: c++, ios, objective-c, componentkit

I am trying to implement the following layout:

```
     Name: James
   Gender: Male
Followers: Brian, Jason and Mike.
```

I can imagine that the top level is to use CKStackLayout, but for each entry, e.g. "Name: James", how can I make the Name right align within a Box?

I was using something like the following, wrap the text within a fixed width component and set the label component to use `NSTextAlignmentRight` alignment, but it doesn't work and both left and right are just 'left-align':

```
static CKComponent *singleLine(NSString *left, NSString *right)
{
  CKStackLayoutComponent *stackComponent =
  [CKStackLayoutComponent
   newWithView:{}
   size:{}
   style:{
     .direction = CKStackLayoutDirectionHorizontal,
     .alignItems = CKStackLayoutAlignItemsStretch,}
       children:{
         {.component = [CKStaticLayoutComponent 
                        newWithView:{}
                        size:{.width = CKRelativeDimension(10)}]},
         {.component =
           [CKStaticLayoutComponent
            newWithView:{}
            size:{.width = CKRelativeDimension(88)}
            children:{
            {
            .component =
            [CKLabelComponent
             newWithLabelAttributes:{
               .string = left,
               .alignment = NSTextAlignmentRight,
               .font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:14.0],
               .maximumNumberOfLines = 1
             }
             viewAttributes:{}],
          }
        }],
     },
     {
       .component =
       [CKLabelComponent
        newWithLabelAttributes:{
          .string = right,
          .alignment = NSTextAlignmentLeft,
          .font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:14.0],
          .maximumNumberOfLines = 1
        }
        viewAttributes:{}],
       .spacingBefore = 10.0
     }
   }];

  return stackComponent;
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: I ended up using
".size = CKRelativeSizeRange(CKRelativeSize(CKRelativeDimension(88), 0), {})" within the `CKStaticLayoutComponent`. Basically adding a min width to the `CKLabelComponent` and then the text is right alignment within that bounds.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your solution is a good one. An alternate solution would be to write your own custom layout by overriding `computeLayoutThatFits:`. It's best to avoid this generally, but for complex layouts like forms it can be a lifesaver.

Comment: Thanks Adam! That's helpful

Answer (score 0):

May be you should give the outer stacklout(which wrap multil single line, and has the vertical layout direction): .alignItems = CKStackLayoutAlignItemsStretch